# how to remove kafka task?

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I just want a make oracle_connector and i made it.
But i got this error message....

```
[2023-05-07 20:39:26,049] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=oracle_connector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2023-05-07 20:39:26,049] WARN Couldn't commit processed log positions with the source database due to a concurrent connector shutdown or restart (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:243)
[2023-05-07 20:39:31,455] WARN Couldn't resolve server kafka:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka (org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils:75)
[2023-05-07 20:39:31,457] INFO [Producer clientId=UK-dbhistory] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1189)
[2023-05-07 20:39:31,457] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=oracle_connector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:488)
[2023-05-07 20:39:31,458] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=oracle_connector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2023-05-07 20:39:31,459] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=oracle_connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:191)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:441)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:301)
    at io.debezium.relational.history.KafkaDatabaseHistory.start(KafkaDatabaseHistory.java:235)
    at io.debezium.relational.HistorizedRelationalDatabaseSchema.<init>(HistorizedRelationalDatabaseSchema.java:40)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleDatabaseSchema.<init>(OracleDatabaseSchema.java:35)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnectorTask.start(OracleConnectorTask.java:55)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:106)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:415)
    ... 14 more
[2023-05-07 20:39:31,461] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=oracle_connector-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:192)
[2023-05-07 20:39:31,461] INFO Stopping down connector (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:192)
[2023-05-07 20:39:31,462] WARN Could not stop task (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:175)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnectorTask.doStop(OracleConnectorTask.java:129)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.stop(BaseSourceTask.java:206)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.stop(BaseSourceTask.java:176)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.close(WorkerSourceTask.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doClose(WorkerTask.java:168)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:195)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

i think i didn't make topic now
But i made oracle connector well

i made this connector like this

```
{
    "name": "oracle_connector",
    "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.registry.url": "http://0.0.0.0:8081",
    "database.hostname": "mydb",
    "database.port": "port",
    "database.user": "user",
    "database.password": "userpwd",
    "database.dbname": "dbname",
    "topic.prefix": "test_",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.testdb",
    "database.server.name": "servername",
    "database.out.server.name": "servername"
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKaTg.png)

So how can i remove task or how can i make topics?

Comment: `No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers` ... This error has nothing to do with your oracle connector. Is Kafka actually running?